# Pass an extra (second) argument to Guava Predicate

Tags: java, guava

I've got this [`Predicate`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html), which filters my `Task` objects based in a date:

```
Predicate<Task> startDateFiltering = new Predicate<Task>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Task input) {
        return input.getStartDate() != null
                && input.getStartDate().after(date);
    }

};
```

There's no problem to use it as long as `date` variable is accessible in the context. However, I'll like to make it reusable and embed it in the `Task` class itself, doing something like this:

```
public static final Predicate<Task> startDateFiltering = new Predicate<Task>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Task input) {
        return input.getStartDate() != null
                && input.getStartDate().after(date);
    }

};
```

In order to access it as `Task.startDateFiltering` each time I need it. But how to pass the `date` argument to it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd create a `static` factory method (or just directly a new instance every time)

```
public static Predicate<Task> startDateFilteringWithDate(final Date date) {
    return new Predicate<Task>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Task input) {
            return input.getStartDate() != null
                && input.getStartDate().after(date);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it into a method (`Factory pattern` kind of).

```
public static Predicate<Task> startDateFiltering(Date date) {
    return new Predicate<Task>() {
       public boolean apply(Task input) {
             return input.getStartDate() != null
            && input.getStartDate().after(date);
       }
    }
 }
```